# How to set the min date to the datetimepicker

Tags: datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am currently having a start and end datetimepicker. The condition is the start time value cannot be greater than the end value or the start value cannot be less than the end value. If any of the events happen, I need to default the date value to min value.

Here is my code

```
$("#endTime").on("dp.change",function (e) {
        var fromDate = $("#startTime").find("input").val();
        alert("fromDate" + fromDate);
        var toDate = $("#endTime").find("input").val();
        alert("toDate" + toDate);

        if(fromDate>toDate==1 || fromDate<toDate== -1)
        {
            $('#endTime').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(new Date(toYear, toMonth, toDay, 18,00,00))
        }
    });
```

How to reset the date values to a default or min value?